# Create PDF front end service

Tags: mysql, database, pdf, adobe, hosting

I have a MySQL database that I would like to periodically print reports from.
I would like these reports to be downloadable into .pdf format; are there any free (secure) services that would allow me to do this?

Preferably from a well-known hosting service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One that I have used and really like is [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/).

It's a PHP Module Library that works really well and best of all it's free!

There are example scripts on their website too for you too have a look and plenty of tutorials on YouTube.

Hope this helps,

Craig

Comment: Ok Thanks!
I tried to run the example program, but got the following errors...

     PHP Warning:  require(fpdf.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/EXznh4/prog.php on line 2
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'fpdf.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home/EXznh4/prog.php on line 2

Does this mean that I will not be able to run from my own PHP server?

Comment: You need to download the library from http://fpdf.org/en/download.php and save the fpdf.php file to your directory.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try that